# How to resolve unresolved external symbol when linking against dll with static constructors?

Tags: dll, linker, d, unresolved-external

I'm building a dll in D with some utils, tools, ect. I can successfully compile a basic dll and test program to use it in visual D without any issues. I am familiar with the process of creating and using dll's. Especially statically linking against them. But if a module in the dll has a static this(), or imports a module with a static this(), the dll will compile, but any program you build that uses it will fail with a foo.bar.__ModuleInfo being unresolved.

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "dtoolbox.dtoolboxdllmain.__ModuleInfo" (__D8dtoolbox15dtoolboxdllmain12__ModuleInfoZ)

In this case my dllmain module dtoolbox.dtoolboxdllmain imports core.runtime which has a static this() so i get this error. How do i resolve this? What are static module constructors doing to cause this? As long as there are no static constructors everything works fine.

[edit] Importing core.runtime wasn't the problem, it was the modules own static this(), not core.runtime's static this().

Comment: What does the source import file look like? Are you importing the original .d file or is it one with function bodies stripped out (aka .di file)?

Comment: Adam, you answered by asking. For some reason, i was importing the original .d file, in this case the file with dllmain. Which i never even needed to import as it didn't export any usable functions. I removed the import from the test project and everything works fine. I did some tests, and found out that you cant directly import modules with static this(), i assume thats what a .di is for?

Comment: Yeah, the di file (which is actually just a D file; the compiler treats them exactly the same, but by convention we name it .di when the bodies are stripped out) lets you hide those kind of internal details from the caller. You can take module ctor/dtors out (that is handled internally to the dll), most function bodies, most private members - to hide anything except the minimum required interface. You might want to write this as an answer to yourself btw for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to refrain from importing a module with the dll's static this() && static ~this() into a module of a program which uses the dll. (In this case the dllmain module was being imported, for no reason at all, my mistake) Not to say that the dll can not have them though, they just need to be there in some file when compiling the dll. I found it convenient to write them in the same module as your dllmain as this file will never really need to be referenced/imported by a program using the dll.